# Exclude element in array when iterating using map

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, array-map

I have code like below

```
let myNums = getXYZ(nums: [1,2,3,4,5])

func getXYZ(nums: [Int]) -> [Int] {
let newNum = nums.map { (num) -> Int in

    if num == 2 {
    //do something and continue execution with next element in list like break/fallthrough
        return 0
    }
    return num
}

return newNum

}

print(myNums)`
```

This prints [1,0,3,4,5]

but i want the output to be [1,3,4,5]. How can I exclude 2? I want to alter the if statement used so as to not include in array when it sees number 2

I have to use .map here but to exclude 2..is there any possibility

Please let me know

Comment: use compactMap and return nil when num == 2

Comment: it says " nil is incompatible with return type 'Int'"

Comment: try koropok's suggestion with flatMap

Comment: flatMap is depraced also it returns same error even with flatMap " nil is incompatible with return type 'Int'".  I tried if num == 2 { return nil }

Comment: Like what koropok said use `compactMap` and inside your closure make your return type nullable like so `(num) -> Int?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply do a `filter` as described as your problem, you want to `filter` the numbers by removing another number.

```
var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let excludeNums = [2]

let newNum = myNums.filter({ !excludeNums.contains($0) })

print(newNum) //1, 3, 4, 5
```

If you need to do a map, you could do a `map` first then `filter`.

```
let newNum = myNums.map({ $0*2 }).filter({ !excludeNums.contains($0) })
print(newNum) //4, 6, 8, 10
```

This maps to multiplying both by `2` and then filtering by removing the new `2` from the list. If you wanted to remove the initial `2` you would have to filter first then map. Since both return a `[Int]` you can call the operations in any order, as you deem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @koropok, I had to make below changes

nums.compactMap { (num) -> Int? in
....
if num == 2 {
return nil
}

Comment: you can just use `Shorthand Argument Names` for inline closures. remove (num) -> int? and replace num == 2 with $0 == 2.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use filter instead of map:

```
let myNums = [1,2,3,4,5]
let result1 = myNums.filter{ return $0 != 2 }
print(result1) // This will print [1,3,4,5]
```

If you must definitely use map, then use compactMap:

```
let result2 = myNums.compactMap { return $0 == 2 ? nil : $0 }
print(result2) // This will print [1,3,4,5]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can shorten the `compactMap` version by getting rid of the `return` (in Swift 5, at least).

Answer (score 1):

`filter` is more appropriate than `map` for your use case.

If you want to exclude only 1 number:

```
func getXYZ(nums: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return nums.filter { $0 != 2 }
}
```

If you want to exclude a list of numbers, store those exclusions in a `Set` since `Set.contains` runs in `O(1)` time, whereas `Array.contains` runs in `O(n)` time.

```
func getXYZ(nums: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let excluded: Set<Int> = [2,4]
    return nums.filter { !excluded.contains($0) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on `enumerated()` method:

```
let elements = nums.enumerated().compactMap { (index, value) in
                    ( index == 0 ) ? nil : value
                }
```

`enumerated()` add element's index as first closure argument